# which of the following are compact..?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the partial order in $\mathbb{R^2}$ given by the relation $(x_1,y_1) < (x_2,y_2)$ Either  if  $x_1 <x_2$ or if $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$  then in   the order topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the above order

choose the coorect statement

a) $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ is compact but $[0,1] \times[0,1]$ is not compact

b) $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is compact but $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ is not compact

c) both $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ are   compacts

d)both $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ are not compacts

## My attempt  : i got  answer  option $c)$

i was try visulalize the diagram i got  option c  that is  both $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ are  compacts,  both are  closed and bounded[image]

Edit : according to henno sir[image]

Is my logic  is right or wrong pliz verified

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: The definition of compact is not "closed and bounded" in arbitrary topological spaces, only in complete metric spaces. Here the topology does not necessarily come from a metric, so you should use the more general definition of compact.

Comment: @MichaelLee Even in complete metric spaces it would be "totally bounded" and closed (not just bounded); consider the discrete metric, e.g.

Comment: Your pictures are misleading BTW, now it seems the sets are the same (at least to me)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma sir   how  my picture  is misleading??

Comment: You colour in the area between $0$ and $1$ in the bottom picture.

Comment: ya @henno sir  i got  it  from  page no : 85  from  munkre books  here http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math205B-2018/Munkres%20-%20Topology.pdf

Comment: @jasmine dead link and it's not in my copies of Munkres.

Comment: $[0,1]\times \{1\}$ is a line segment.

Comment: @henno sir that is  munkre topology 2nd edition

Comment: how $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ is  line  segment ?,,as here $x \in [0,1]$ and  $y  = 1$ ?? im not getting that

Comment: @jasmine It's a line segment at "height"  $1$ yes.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, of course, thank you. Alternatively, "closed and bounded" only works in Euclidean spaces.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma sir i  have edits  its  pliz look that picture  that is correct or not?

Comment: No, it's the top line of the square only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[0,1] \times [0,1]$ fulfills the definition of a linear continuum (Munkres' style) so is compact (every subset has a supremum) but $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ is not compact. So b) is in fact correct.

$[0,1] \times \{1\}$ is homeomorphic to  $[0,1]$ as a subset of the lower limit topology (using $(x,1) \to x$) and this is not compact as $1-\frac1n$ is a sequence without a cluster point, and it's a first countable space. Or use the cover $[0,x)$, $x < 1$ with $\{1\}$ that has no finite subcover.

Comment: thanks u @henno sir